# Echo String dont work properly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm using cakePHP 2.x. I'm trying to render a view with an empty layout. The view should contain only a string returned from the action controller with no html code.
Here is the code:

```
 public function checkout(){

     $ref =null;$act=null;$par=null;

     $this->layout = false;
     //$this->render(false);

     //$priceCTP = $this->Session->read('priceCTP');;
     $priceCTP = $this->getPrice();
     //var_dump(session_save_path());

     if (isset($this->params['url']['Reference'])) {
         $ref = $this->params['url']['Reference'];
     }
     if (isset($this->params['url']['Action'])) {
         $act = $this->params['url']['Action'];
     }
     if (isset($this->params['url']['Param'])) {
         $par = $this->params['url']['Param'];//$_GET['Param'];//this->request->params['named']
     }
     switch ($act) {
         case "DETAIL":// accéder à la base et récuperer le montant
             echo "Reference=".$ref."&Action=".$act."&Reponse=".$priceCTP;
             break;
         case "ERREUR": // accéder à la base et mettre à jour l’état de la transaction
             echo "Reference=".$ref. "&Action=".$act. "&Reponse=OK";
             break;
         case "ACCORD": // accéder à la base, enregistrer le numéro d’autorisation (dans param)
             echo "Reference=".$ref. "&Action=".$act. "&Reponse=OK";
             break;
         case "REFUS":  // accéder à la base et mettre à jour l’état de la transaction
             echo "Reference=".$ref. "&Action=".$act. "&Reponse=OK";
             break;
         case "ANNULATION":  // accéder à la base et mettre à jour l’état de la transaction
             echo "Reference=".$ref. "&Action=".$act. "&Reponse=OK";
             break;
     }
}
```

the result on this url(http://mydomain/orders/checkout?

```
Reference=123&Action=DETAIL&Param=)

"Reference=123&Action=DETAIL&Repon"
rather than 
"Reference=123&Action=DETAIL&Reponse=121,630" (works fine on localhost).
```

Comment: How are you fetching the output of this script? Through a browser or a client like CURL?

Comment: thx for the quick reply. I'm testing it through a browser.

Comment: use `if( ! empty($priceCTP))` to ensure the variable `$priceCTP` is not empty

Comment: @ Yu Jiaao  Thank you for the advice

Comment: Controller actions should never echo data! You should instead prepare the request object or use a (data) view. That being said, please make sure that the details you present are correct, from your question it reads as if the output would be cut off after `&Repon` (ie it's not just that the price is missing)?

Comment: @ndm Yes exact, the output is cut off after &Respon. Can you please give me an example of how I will use a data view. Before I post the question I have try to set the output to the view but It doesnt work. The output will be used by a payment system so it should not contain html.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Do not echo data from controllers

As mentioned in the comments, controller actions are not supposed to echo data, even though it might work in some, maybe even most situations. The correct way of outputting data is by using (data) views, by configuring and return the response object, or even returning a string (which however isn't forward compatible with future versions of CakePHP).

Echoing data can lead to all kinds of problems, from the data not being recognized in the test environment, to headers not being able to be sent, and even data being cut off, which is what you are experiencing. The latter can for example happen when the size sent in the `Content-Length` header doesn't match the actual size of the data being sent, this often happens in situations where the content is being gzipped.

### Content-Length mismatch is likely the cause

If you've run into the length mismatch for gzipped responses problem, then you have to figure out where compression is being involved (on server level (for example `mod_deflate`), on PHP extension level (for example `zlib`), on PHP code level (for example `CakeResponse::compress()`)), and why it doesn't set the proper length accordingly.

### Proper controller action logic

That being said, just pass the required data to the view, and build and echo the reponse data from there. Given that you don't want to respond with HTML, you probably also want to set the response type accordingly:

```
public function checkout()
{
    $this->response->type('text'); // = text/plain

    // ...

    $this->set(compact(array('priceCTP', 'ref', 'act', 'par')));
}
```

As mentioned, another option would be to return a proper response object:

```
public function checkout()
{
    $this->response->type('text');

    // ...
    
    $body = "Reference=" . $ref . "&Action=" . $act . "&Reponse=";
    switch ($act) {
        case "DETAIL":
            $body .= $priceCTP;
            break;

        case "ERREUR":
        case "ACCORD":
        case "REFUS":
        case "ANNULATION": 
            $body .= "OK";
            break;
        
        // ...
    }
    
    // ...

    $this->response->body($body);
    return $this->response;
}
```

ps. do you really want to respond with a key in french? `Reponse` maybe should be `Response`.

pps. given that you respond with a query string, you may want/need to URL encode the values accordingly.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Controller actions](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#controller-actions)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Request > Request and Response objects > CakeResponse > Dealing with content types](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#dealing-with-content-types)**

Comment: Thank you man for your reply. I ve tried your solution, the output was between a <pre> and cut off after &Repon. I m sure that's the right way but I think  I'm missing something. P.S Yes the key should be in french. Here is the output: <body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; ">Reference=123&Action=DETAIL&Repon</pre></body>

Comment: @Ninja Sounds like you're looking at the content via your browsers DOM inspection functionality - that will not show you the actual raw content (especially not for non-HTML)! Make sure to use the source view functionality instead. If your content is still cut-off with the solutions mentioned in my answer, then you need to debug things further, starting with checking the mentioned `Content-Length` header. `Content-Encoding` may play a part in this too.

Comment: Im confused. I have do a var_dump($body) and the output is: string(44) "Reference=123&Action=DETAIL&Reponse=1079,764" but with return $this->response;   the content is cut off : Reference=123&Action=DETAIL&Repon

Comment: @Ninja Via `CakeResponse::length()`, but you normally don't do that! CakePHP does that for you unless the response is going to be compressed via PHP. Looking at your link, your server responds with the same length for compressed as well as uncompressed reponses, and that's where the problem stems from. You have to figure out where compression is being involved (on server level (eg `mod_deflate`), on PHP extension level (eg `zlib`), on PHP code level (eg `CakeResponse::compress()`)), and why it doesn't set the proper length accordingly.

Comment: Thank you man! you made my day!! now the output is not cut off. just I have to remove the <pre> so the payment system will read the output properly.

Comment: @Ninja There should be no `<pre>` in the response, and there actually is none looking at your link. As mentioned, don't use DOM inspection to look at the source.