# CakePHP in plugin can't Load model

Tags: apache, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Im using plugin, I want just to load data from my table as json, the problem is in local it's working and in the server I found this error in log :

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

my model:

```
<?php
class Indisponibilite extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Indisponibilite';

}
```

my function:

```
public function getIndisponible () {

    $indisponibles = ClassRegistry::init('Indisponibilite')->find('all');

    echo json_encode($indisponibles);

    $this->layout = 'ajax';  
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->render(false, "ajax");
    error_reporting(0);

}
```

Comment: As the error message suggests, check [**the server error log**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6438475/1392379) (**http://stackoverflow.com/q/5127838/1392379**). Side note, controller actions [**shouldn't echo data**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43147620/1392379)!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Please check the docs about [JSON Views](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html) which are much more MVC and Cake-ish. For Cake 2.x check [here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).

Also, don’t set `error_reporting`. CakePHP should handle all this for you. Setting `Configure::write('debug', 0)` will turn off error_reporting for you.

To find your error, check the logs, turn on `debug` and see what’s up there.

Comment: my application on server now, I cant find the log error.. where I can find it  please !

Comment: This strongly depends on your server setup, probably in a folder `log`. The CakePHP `error` and `debug` logs can be found in `/logs`. Is the action you described the only one that’s not working?

Comment: yes it's only not working when I call that model I found Internal Server Error !